# Options for displaying DynamoDB table on a webpage

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We use Amazon's DynamoDB to store configuration details for a system at my company.

We now need to display a certain DynamoDB table on a webpage for people to see in a filterable/searchable format. What is my best option here? I'd prefer to use jquery, but that doesn't necessarily matter.

Comment: not really a dynamo question. you can grab the data and how you display it depends on what you want to use. It's not bound to dynamo in any way

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Do you know of nay good frameworks to display tabular data?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [DynamoDB Document JS SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk) available in awslabs on GitHub that you can use in addition to the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js).